# Can Vim reference a font stored locally in .vim or vimfiles?

Tags: vim, fonts, macvim

I have my Vim configuration under source control, and instead of moving to a new platform and having to install the specific Powerline font I use on every machine, I'd like to be able to simply store my font in something like `~/.vim/fonts/my-powerline-font.ttf`, so I can use a command in my `vimrc` to reference it locally.

Is this possible?

Comment: sounds like a question for superuser or something?

Comment: No. what you want is not possible: you have to install that font if you want GVim/MacVim to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Like any other application, Vim uses the operating system's APIs to use one of the installed fonts. If a font is not properly installed, Vim cannot use it.

So, you need to install any font first. You *could* automate that by invoking external commands in your `~/.vimrc`, though. For example, on Linux, "installing" can be as easy as copying the font into `~/.fonts`:

```
if ! file_readable($HOME . '/.fonts/my-powerline-font.ttf')
    call system('cp ~/.vim/fonts/my-powerline-font.ttf ~/.fonts/')
fi
```